# Why does this cause XSS? And how can I prevent it?

Tags: php, xss

This is my source code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>XSS</title>
    <script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    var output = "";
    <?php
    if (isset($_GET['q'])) {
      printf('output = "%s";', htmlspecialchars($_GET['q'],ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'));
    }
    ?>

    $(function()  {
      $("#output").html(output);
    });
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p id="output"></p>
  </body>
</html>
```

When I send `q=\x3cscript\x3ealert(1)\x3c/script\x3e` to my script, the alert is fired. How can I prevent this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP functions for preventing XSS](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/8798/php-functions-for-preventing-xss)

Answer (score 8):

Escaping is context sensitive. You are escaping for HTML, but are using the variable in Javascript. Instead, correctly encode for JavaScript using [`json_encode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php):

```
printf('output = %s;', json_encode($_GET['q']));
```

Also, you are using the `html` function even though you don't seem to want HTML at all. What you probably want is the [`text` function](http://api.jquery.com/text/):

```
$("#output").text(output);
```

Comment: Just a thought: would json_encode catch </script><script>alert(1) ?

Comment: @paj28 Yes, it encodes the slash as `\/`.